# Writing data to master Google Spreadsheet from multiple other sheets; am overwriting results of each feeder sheet instead of getting all results

Tags: google-apps-script

**Situation:** Aggregating information from several feeder Trixes and trying to populate the results from feeders to one sheet of a master Trix.

**Problem:**  I want to write the results of each feeder trix (gathered with get_data_from_feeders() function below), to the same sheet in a Master Trix.  However, each feeder array overwrites the previous feeder results, so only the last feeder trix results are shown in the Master Trix instead of all three (write_data(data) function below).

**Questions:**

1) How can I make each feeder set of results append the previous feeder trix results instead of overwriting them? [This will be run monthly, so each month it's okay to overwrite what had been on the sheet from last month]

2) How can I sort all of the results (I think I use .sort() but am unsure where to call it)?

**Current code:**

```
function get_data_from_feeders() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var feeders = ss.getRangeByName('spokes').getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i <= feeders.length; i++) {
    var feeder_id = feeders[i][0];
    var feeder_open = SpreadsheetApp.openById(feeder_id);
    var dataPull = feeder_open.getRangeByName('dataPull').getValues(); 

  write_data(dataPull); 
  }
}

function write_data(data) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Forecast_Aggregation");
  var dataDump = ss.getRangeByName("data_dump");

// I think the next line is where my code is incorrect - each feeder goes back to same cell instead of to the next blank row (hence, overwriting instead of appending)

  ws.getRange(dataDump.getRowIndex(), 2, data.length, 20).setValues(data);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try:

```
function write_data(data) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Forecast_Aggregation");
  var dataDump = ss.getRangeByName("data_dump").getRow();
  var nextRow = Math.max(dataDump, ws.getLastRow())+1;
  ws.getRange(nextRow, 2, data.length, 20).setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @AdamL!  I kept working at it yesterday as well and came up with a similar solution, though I like how you kept the named range intact.  I found that it was easier to make the range for dataDump dynamic rather than a named range, so I changed the code to remove dataDump and replace it with : `var firstEmptyRow= ws.getLastRow()+1 and ws.getRange(firstEmptyRow, 2, data.length, data.length[0]).setValues(data);`, which worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to review a blog of mine, too.
http://blog.ditoweb.com/2012/01/consolidate-spreadsheet-sheets-with.html